# configure Tomcat 6 with IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have legacy java, which wants to run on tomcat 6.
Now, i got tomcat 7 configured somewhat easily using tutorial.
Download, extract, give permissions and it appeared as usable server in intelliJ.
But it was not old enough..

However, same is not working with tomcat 6

I can see tomcat 6 is using different layout for content, but i have no idea how to configure it on intelliJ

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add it to project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined tomcat's **src** folder instead of **bin** folder. 
IntelliJ IDEA recognizes Tomcat 6 as predictable for me: 
[image]
So, please download suitable distribution here: 
https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.9/bin/

Comment: Whelp... yeah.. i have accidentally downloaded src package... off to next problem. thank you!